# Determine memory modules installed without looking inside the box

Tags: vmware-esx, xenserver

Is there a way to determine the physical memory configuration of a server that's running ESX Server or XenServer? If the server was running bare metal on Windows, I'd use the excellent CPU-Z utility which displays information about the slot usage.

This could be a Linux shell question (not my speciality) as that's what I think ESX Server and XenCenter are based around.

Failing this, I'm going to have to take the servers down and look inside the box :-(

Thanks, Rob.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`dmidecode` run in dom0 or the host should be able to tell you what memory modules you have.

Comment: As of ESX 3.x, dmidecode output is included in the vm-support if the
utility is there.

Comment: +1  Good call on dmidecode

Comment: dmidecode works well on both ESX Server and XenServer so thanks, question answered. Pipe the output into a file and search for "DIMM" finds the memory information

Answer (score 1):

If the server is a HP, I'd say to check the iLO or the System Management Homepage (SMH).  (You *did* install the PSP, didn't you...?)

I'm sure other brand-name servers have similar Lights-Out management info available, too...

Comment: I'll confirm that this info is available on Sun servers through their iLOM cards as well.

Answer (score 1):

dmidecode is now deprecated. For ESXi 5+ consider using smbiosDump.